# Multiple apps per domain or one app per domain in Payara (Glassfish)

Tags: glassfish, war, payara

I have two WAR applications running on a [Payara](https://www.payara.fish/) server (a Glassfish fork). However, when deploying them in production, currently I deploy each one in an independent domain (one domain per application).

To simplify the process, I'm planning to merge both domains, i.e., deploy both applications on the same domain. *Is there any performance issue with 
this approach?*

Or maybe it's advisable to keep them on independent domains?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

This is a bit of a subjective topic, but there are some clear objective things to consider:

- If you deploy two applications to the same server instance, then a problem with Application X is much more likely to affect Application Y, e.g. a memory leak in one app would take out both of them
- If you wanted to make changes to Payara Server for one application, you would have to factor these in to the other application, e.g. changing connection pool sizes/behaviour will have an impact on the overall amount of resources and work that the server will need to do.
- If you need easier management, then a better solution would be to create two Standalone Instances and deploy an application to each instance. This has the benefit of keeping each application to its own JVM with its own configuration. You will also not be deploying to the Administration server (DAS) so any problems with one application will not affect your ability to manage the other application.

Since you are using Payara Server, you may want to consider Payara Micro for easy management of multiple servers. It's designed to run one app per container and may make deployments easier for you.